# Bash script: how to get the whole command line which ran the script

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I would like to run a bash script and be able to see the command line used to launch it:

```
sh myscript.sh arg1 arg2 1> output 2> error
```

**in order to know** if the user used the "**std redirection**" '1>' and '2>', and therefore adapt the output of my script.

Is it possible with built-in variables ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux and some unix-like systems, `/proc/self/fd/1` and `/proc/self/fd/2` are symlinks to where your *std redirections* are pointing to. Using `readlink`, we can query if they were redirected or not by comparing them to the parent process' file descriptor.

We will however not use `self` but `$$` because `$(readlink /proc/"$$"/fd/1)` spawns a new shell so self would no longer refer to the current bash script but to a subshell.

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#errRedirected=false
#outRedirected=false
parentStderr=$(readlink /proc/"$PPID"/fd/2)
currentStderr=$(readlink /proc/"$$"/fd/2)
parentStdout=$(readlink /proc/"$PPID"/fd/1)
currentStdout=$(readlink /proc/"$$"/fd/1)
[[ "$parentStderr" == "$currentStderr" ]] || errRedirected=true
[[ "$parentStdout" == "$currentStdout" ]] || outRedirected=true

echo "$0 ${outRedirected:+>$currentStdout }${errRedirected:+2>$currentStderr }$@"

$ ./test.sh
./test.sh

$ ./test.sh 2>/dev/null
./test.sh 2>/dev/null

$ ./test.sh arg1 2>/dev/null # You will lose the argument order!
./test.sh 2>/dev/null arg1

$ ./test.sh arg1 2>/dev/null >file ; cat file
./test.sh >/home/camusensei/file 2>/dev/null arg1

$
```

Do not forget that the user can also redirect to a **3rd** file descriptor which is open on something else...!

Comment: I Fixed the problem with stdout which didn't work using `$(readlink /proc/self/fd/1)`

Comment: I answered the question by providing the `whole command line which ran the script`. The argument order won't be the same for the redirections though.

Comment: That is not true. It works in all *unix* environments, I tested it on windows via cygwin. But yeah, you need an **unix** environment... OP uses `sh` to run his scripts and the `bash` tag, so I assume he has this environment available.

Comment: Really? OpenBSD: `$ ls /proc` - `ls: /proc: No such file or directory`.  FreeBSD: `$ ls /proc/$$/fd` - `ls: /proc/1022/fd: No such file or directory` (and that after explicitly mounting `/proc`).  Must be that OpenBSD and FreBSD are not really UNIXen then. :)

Comment: My bad :( I didn't know the fd directory was linux-only thank you for the precision, I'll update the answer

Comment: The structure of `/proc` is very much system-specific.  Some systems don't have `/proc` at all, others have it only for legacy reasons and don't mount it by default.

Answer (score 2):

Not really possible.  You can check whether `stdout` and `stderr` are pointing to a terminal: `[ -t 1 -a -t 2 ]`.  But if they do, it doesn't necessarily mean they weren't redirected (think `>/dev/tty5`).  And if they don't, you can't distinguish between `stdout` and `stderr` being closed and them being redirected.  And even if you know for sure they *are* redirected, you can't tell from the script itself where they point after redirection.